# Trouble Writing to file in java

Tags: java, writer

Hey im trying to write to a file but im getting an error on the line where it writes the line that goes into each line of a text file, cant figure it out any help would be greatly appreciated
The Writer Code
 .

```
 public static void stuIDWrite() throws IOException
 {
     Writer writer = null;

 try {
     writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
           new FileOutputStream("Res/stuIDSorted.txt")));
 } catch (IOException ex) {
   // report
 } finally {
    try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
 }
 int i = 0;

    while (i <= stuArrayIdSort.length + 1)
    {
        ln = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuLastName();    
        fn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
        pn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
        id = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuId();
        ft = stuArrayIdSort[i].getFTime();
        phn =stuArrayIdSort[i].getPhoneNum();
        lj = stuArrayIdSort[i].getLovJava();
        con = stuArrayIdSort[i].getCont();
            writer.write(ln + "," + fn + "," + pn  + ","+ id + "," + ft + "," + phn + "," + lj + "," + con + "\n");
            writer.close();
            i++;    
    }
```

The Full Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class StudentMain {
    /**
     * @param args
     */

        //array and sorting variables
     public static studentConstructor[] stuArrayOrig = new studentConstructor[23];
     private static studentConstructor[] stuArrayIdSort = new studentConstructor[23];
     private static studentConstructor[] stuArrayNameSort = new studentConstructor[23];
     private static int lineCount = 0;
     private static int nElms = 0;

     //writer


     //studentConstructor variables 
        public static String fn; //First Name
        public static String ln; //Last Name
        public static String pn; //Preferred Name
        public static int id;     //Student Id Number
        public static boolean ft;//Full-time Boolean
        public static int phn;   //Student Phone Number
        public static boolean lj;//Loving java Boolean
        public static String con;//Continuing 


        File idSort = new File("stuListSortID.txt");


     public static void StuRead()
     {

        Scanner inFile = null;

         try
         {
             inFile = new Scanner
                    (new FileReader("Res/students.txt"));
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             System.out.println("File Not Found");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

            while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
                        inFile.useDelimiter(",|\\n"); //breaks the lines into single info

                        ln = inFile.next();
                            System.out.println(ln);

                        fn = inFile.next();
                            System.out.println(fn);

                        pn = inFile.next();
                            System.out.println(pn);

                        id = inFile.nextInt();
                            System.out.println(id);

                        ft = inFile.nextBoolean();
                            System.out.println(ft);

                        phn = inFile.nextInt();
                            System.out.println(phn);

                        lj = inFile.nextBoolean();
                            System.out.println(lj);

                        con = inFile.next();
                            System.out.println(con);

                            studentConstructor st = new studentConstructor(ln, fn, pn, id, ft, phn, lj, con);
                            stuArrayOrig[lineCount] = st;
                            inFile.nextLine();
                            System.out.println(stuArrayOrig[lineCount]);


                        lineCount++;
                    }
            //setting info into other arrays
            stuArrayIdSort = stuArrayOrig;
            stuArrayNameSort = stuArrayOrig;            

            System.out.println("orig array length" + stuArrayOrig.length);
            System.out.println("id array length" + stuArrayIdSort.length);
            System.out.println("name array length" + stuArrayNameSort.length);
            System.out.println("number of file lines" + lineCount);




            inFile.close(); 


    }    

     public static void stuIdSort()
     {
         studentConstructor temp;
         boolean sorted = false;

         while (sorted == false)
         {  sorted=true;
            for (int i=0; i<stuArrayIdSort.length-1 ; i++)
            {
                if(stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuId() > stuArrayIdSort[i+1].getStuId())
                {
                    temp = stuArrayIdSort[i+1];
                    stuArrayIdSort[i+1] = stuArrayIdSort[i];
                    stuArrayIdSort[i] = temp;
                    sorted=false;

                }
            }
        }
         for(int i=0; i<stuArrayIdSort.length; i++)
         {
             int getSC = stuArrayIdSort[i].studentId;
             System.out.println("number of swaps " + i+1 +" " +getSC);
         }
     }

    //stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuLastName(),stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName(),stuArrayIdSort[i].getPrefName(),stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuId(),stuArrayIdSort[i].getFTime(),stuArrayIdSort[i].getPhoneNum(),stuArrayIdSort[i].getLovJava(),stuArrayIdSort[i].getCont()
     public static void stuIDWrite() throws IOException
     {
         Writer writer = null;

         try {
             writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                   new FileOutputStream("Res/stuIDSorted.txt")));
         } catch (IOException ex) {
           // report
         } finally {
            try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
         }
         int i = 0;

            while (i <= stuArrayIdSort.length + 1)
            {
                ln = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuLastName();    
                fn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
                pn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
                id = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuId();
                ft = stuArrayIdSort[i].getFTime();
                phn =stuArrayIdSort[i].getPhoneNum();
                lj = stuArrayIdSort[i].getLovJava();
                con = stuArrayIdSort[i].getCont();
                    writer.write(ln + "," + fn + "," + pn  + ","+ id + "," + ft + "," + phn + "," + lj + "," + con + "\n");
                    writer.close();
                    i++;    
            }
     }

     public static void stuNameSort()
     {

     }

     public static void stuNameWrire()
     {

     }
}
//lastName, firstName, perName, studentId, fulltime,
```

Comment: sorry the error
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
 at StudentMain.stuIDWrite(StudentMain.java:152)

Comment: move the writer.close function invocation out of the while loop in your stuIDWrite function.

Comment: You are calling `writer.close()` first and then trying to write to the stream. Why shouldn't it complain?

Comment: Try to post the code with precise point of problem.

Comment: Thanks move the wirter.close to outside the while loop, but im still getting an IO exception error on

writer.write(ln + "," + fn + "," + pn  + ","+ id + "," + ft + "," + phn + "," + lj + "," + con + "\n");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is what you should do:

What's happening is that you are closing it before it can actually do anything. So, lets move your finally clause to the end of everything:

```
public static void stuIDWrite() throws IOException
 {
     Writer writer = null;

 try {
     writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
       new FileOutputStream("Res/stuIDSorted.txt")));

 int i = 0;

while (i <= stuArrayIdSort.length + 1)
{
    ln = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuLastName();    
    fn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
    pn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
    id = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuId();
    ft = stuArrayIdSort[i].getFTime();
    phn =stuArrayIdSort[i].getPhoneNum();
    lj = stuArrayIdSort[i].getLovJava();
    con = stuArrayIdSort[i].getCont();
        writer.write(ln + "," + fn + "," + pn  + ","+ id + "," + ft + "," + phn + "," + lj + "," + con + "\n");
        i++;    
}
} catch (IOException ex) {
   // report
  } finally {
try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
 }
```

Comment: You are still closing the writer inside the while loop. This won't work.

Comment: @mttdbrd No I am not.. Look again :P

Comment: Yup. It's right there, inside the while loop: writer.close();

Comment: Haha, sorry didn't see that - It was just the code copied from above. I was paying attention to the finally. I'll remove that line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand how try...catch...finally works. Here's what you have:

```
     Writer writer = null;

     try {
         writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
               new FileOutputStream("Res/stuIDSorted.txt")));
     } catch (IOException ex) {
       // report
     } finally {
    >>>>>>>  **try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}**
     }
     int i = 0;

        while (i <= stuArrayIdSort.length + 1)
        {
           //bunch of stuff
                writer.write(...);
    >>>>>>>    **writer.close();**
                i++;    
        }
 }
```

You close writer ONCE before you've even used it (finally block gets executed after the try block), and ONCE inside the loop. So, if somehow the code could make it past the writer.close() in the finally block, it would never make it through the loop more than once.

It is not necessary to close a BufferedWriter. The class makes sure to close it internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7, you might want to consider using the ["try-with-resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax, which can simplify a correct implementation of file handling greatly in cases like this.  Your original code had some issues, but even the accepted answer has some problems that I believe will result in a `NullPointerException` in the case where the file can't be opened (unverified).

I think you may also have some problems with your while loop boundary conditions also.  I've changed the `while` loop to the more traditional `for` loop.  Keep in mind that java array elements run from `0` to `array.length - 1` inclusive.

```
  public static void stuIDWrite() throws IOException
  {
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Res/stuIDSorted.txt"))
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < stuArrayIdSort.length; ++i)
      {
        ln = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuLastName();
        fn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
        pn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuFirstName();
        id = stuArrayIdSort[i].getStuId();
        ft = stuArrayIdSort[i].getFTime();
        phn = stuArrayIdSort[i].getPhoneNum();
        lj = stuArrayIdSort[i].getLovJava();
        con = stuArrayIdSort[i].getCont();
        writer.write(ln + "," + fn + "," + pn + "," + id + "," + ft + "," + phn + "," + lj + "," + con + "\n");
      }
    }
  }
```

You could also look at using the ["enhanced for loop"](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) syntax for the inner loop that may further streamline things.